# Algoritmo de ordenação não funciona

Tags: c, algoritmo

Falta alguma coisa no programa. Ele faz a verificação da ordem com um único número ou uma única vez.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

  /*4)escrever 10 números e ordenar em forma crescente e decrescente*/

int main()
{
    int opc;
    int numA=0, numB=0, numC=0, soma, aux=0, i;
    int vet[10];
    float media;

    printf("escolha qual exercicio quer executar:\n1)Ex1\n2)Ex2\n3)Ex3\n4)Ex4\n");
    scanf("%i", &opc);

    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");

    switch(opc)
    {
    case 4:

        printf("digite 10 numeros aleatorios:\n");

        /*inicio da fase de processamento*/
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            scanf("%i", &vet[i]);
        }


    for(i=0; i<10; i++)/*crescente*/
    {
        if(vet[i]>vet[i+1])
        {
            aux=vet[i];
            vet[i]=vet[i+1];
            vet[i+1]=aux;
        }

        printf("%i", vet[i]);
    }

        /*fim da fase de processamento*/

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu algoritmo está errado, pois ele só compara um número com o próximo (sendo que ele precisaria comparar com todos os próximos até o final, considernado que já está ordenado até ele). Dica de leitura: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: concerteza isto esta escrevinhado logo ao fim do primeiro trecho meu caro.

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você quis dizer, meu caro. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da maneira que você está fazendo só troca entre dois elementos, mas não continua fazendo a troca entre todos os elementos. Existem várias formas de resolver isto. Para comparar todos os elementos de forma simples é preciso fazer dois laços para ir comparando cada elemento com todos os os outros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int vet[10];
    int aux;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) scanf("%i", &vet[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) { 
            if(vet[i] > vet[j]) {
                aux = vet[i];
                vet[i] = vet[j];
                vet[j] = aux;
            }
        }
        printf("%i", vet[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MLQoys). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ktegmgmh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Sort.c).

Comment: nossa isso mesmo, é o metodo de boole (algo assim) certo? eu chegei a fazer isso mas fiz com o 'j=0' e nao 'j=i+1', muito obrigado. =) você sempre me ajuda XD

Comment: `j = i + 1` é a forma mais eficiente porque a cada passada você pode ir comparando um elemento a menos já que ele já é certo que está ordenado. Tem maneiras ainda mais eficientes mas são mais complicadas, não acho que seja o seu objetivo.

Comment: lol XD
é eu notei isso @bigown, viu são 12 exercícios se eu tiver mais duvida posso editar a pergunta e você edita a resposta XD

Comment: Não faça isto, se tiver outro problema, poste outra pergunta.

Comment: sempre me falam isso mas tudo bem, sendo q tb a minha duvida pode ser duvida de outro =) mas muito obrigado =) @bigown